# WPF composite/concatenated field

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using MVVM and have a field in my database that is a string and represents a co-ordinate. On screen I want to break it up into coordinate parts for ease of editing by the user. So far I have a class to help:

```
public class Coord
{
    public int LatDegree {get;set;}
    public int LatMinute {get;set;}
    public int LatSecond {get;set;}
    public char Latitude {get;set;}
    public int LonDegree {get;set;}
    public int LonMinute {get;set;}
    public int LonSecond {get;set;}
    public char Longitude {get;set;}

    public Coord(string coord)
    {
            string[] coordAsString =coord.Split(' ');
            this.LatDegree=Int32.Parse(coordAsString[0]);
            this.LatMinute=Int32.Parse(coordAsString[1]);
            this.LatSecond=Int32.Parse(coordAsString[2]);
          this.Latitude = (coordAsString[3].ToCharArray())[0];
            this.LonDegree = Int32.Parse(coordAsString[4]);
            this.LonMinute = Int32.Parse(coordAsString[5]);
          this.LonSecond = Int32.Parse(coordAsString[6]);
          this.Longitude = (coordAsString[7].ToCharArray())[0];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string asString = String.Format(...//omitted for brevity
        return asString;
    }
}
```

in my view model

```
            private Coord relativeGridOrigin;
    private Coord RelativeGridOrigin
    {
        get 
        {
            if(relativeGridOrigin==null)
            {
                relativeGridOrigin = new Coord(myMainObject.relativeGridOrigin);
            }
            return relativeGridOrigin;
        }
        set
        {
            relativeGridOrigin = value;
            myMainObject.relativeGridOrigin = relativeGridOrigin.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and I'm currently binding the lattitude degre control to:

```
            public int LatitudeDegree
    {
        get { return RelativeGridOrigin.LatDegree; }
        set
        {
            RelativeGridOrigin.LatDegree = value;
            myMainObject.relativeGridOrigin = relativeGridOrigin.ToString();
        }
    }
```

But I don't want that LatitudeDegree wrapper (and the other 7 I'd need) - I want to just bind the control to LatDegree in my Coord object, but I need the myMainObject.relativeGridOrigin to change any time one of those 8 values changes _ I think I want that RelativeGridOrigin setter to be called. I think I either need to pass the  RelativeGridOrigin setter into the Coord class or have my view model listen for the Coord class's property changes but I'm not sure how to do either or whether there is another, better way.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what the MVVM pattern calls for: the VM needs to expose any properties the UI will be using. You also need some sort of update notification in the VM, it doesn't look like you have any.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean about needing some sort of update notification. I ended up passing a delegate to update the relativeGridOrigin into the Coord class and having each setter call it, but effectively it's the same as what I was doing above with my LatitudeDegree wrapper. I guess the other way would be to have the Coord class raise an event and listen for it in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Following this answer to another question of mine [MVVM pattern and dependent children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350746/wpf-mvvm-pattern-and-dependent-children)
I realised it was far neater to just raise an event whenever any of the Coord setters changed the value and the VM could then listen to it and update the main object